# R Notebook - code chunk gets separated in preview

Tags: r, rstudio, knitr, r-markdown, rnotebook

I am using R notebook to preview the file. Even though all the code is in one chunk, a line gets separated into two. Would you please tell me how I can resolve this?

As you can see all the code is in one chunk.
[image]

However, when I run this chunk, it gets separated into two.

[image]

I am not sure if it matters but here is the code I am running.

```
library(MASS)
par(mfrow=c(3,1)) 

hist(galaxies, breaks=500)
hist(galaxies, breaks=100)
hist(galaxies, breaks=50)
```

Also here are the versions of R and RStudio. I an new to R so I am not sure what is causing this. If you need any other information, please let me know. Thanks

R version 3.3.2 (2016-10-31)
Rstudio version 1.0.136

Comment: I tried quickly and couldn't reproduce the error, but this could be my error. Perhaps set the knitr chunk option `collapse` to TRUE? (i.e., ```{r collapse=TRUE} ).

Comment: Interesting, if you render it to HTML, it's fine, but if you preview it as an R Notebook, it splits. Looks like a bug.

Comment: @alistaire Yes that is my guess as well but not sure which package/feature might be causing this.

Comment: It's something with `rmarkdown::html_notebook`. If there's no similar issue open, you could file a bug report on GitHub.

Comment: Do you have any news on this topic. I'm dealing with the same problem too and found your post. Did you report that bug or not ?

Comment: I have not yet so please feel free to report the bug. Thanks

Comment: I sent them an email some days now but i got no answer yet. If you find out anything please inform us.